# CSS style of Unordered list

Tags: css, html

I have 10 ULs each with 5 LIs. It looks like a table but I want to have the background only behind the items.
I am trying to do this for an hour. Is it even possible?

[image: My Site]

```
ul {
background: whitesmoke;
padding-top: 0px;
}
ul:nth-child(odd) { background: ghostwhite; }
li:nth-child(3n) {
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
}

li:hover {
background-color: greenyellow;
}

ul:hover {
background-color: yellow;
}

li{
display: inline-table;
padding-top: 0px;
}

ul {
font-size: 1px;

}

ul li {
font-size: 14px;
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
}
```

Comment: show us what you did

Comment: Can you please add code to this and explain what you already tried?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah sorry

Comment: @Tobias I just can make good width of this table

Comment: @RadoSabo can you also add the html?

Comment: @Tobias html is just 5list items in 10 unordered lists and all is in one div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't really understand what your problem is or if I relly provide the right answer but I have this:

## Example

```css
ul {
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 1px;
}

ul:nth-child(odd) li{
    background: black;
    color: blue;
}

ul:nth-child(odd) li:hover{
    background: white;
}

ul:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(3n){
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background: #999;
}

ul:nth-child(odd) li:hover:nth-child(3n){
    background: darkblue;
}

li:nth-child(3n){
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background: #333;
}

li:hover:nth-child(3n){
    background: darkgreen;
}

li:hover {
    background: lightblue;
}

li{
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}

ul li {
    color: green;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>ul 1 ListItem 1</li>
    <li>ul 1 ListItem 2</li>
    <li>ul 1 ListItem 3</li>
    <li>ul 1 ListItem 4</li>
    <li>ul 1 ListItem 5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>ul 2 ListItem 1</li>
    <li>ul 2 ListItem 2</li>
    <li>ul 2 ListItem 3</li>
    <li>ul 2 ListItem 4</li>
    <li>ul 2 ListItem 5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>ul 3 ListItem 1</li>
    <li>ul 3 ListItem 2</li>
    <li>ul 3 ListItem 3</li>
    <li>ul 3 ListItem 4</li>
    <li>ul 3 ListItem 5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>ul 4 ListItem 1</li>
    <li>ul 4 ListItem 2</li>
    <li>ul 4 ListItem 3</li>
    <li>ul 4 ListItem 4</li>
    <li>ul 4 ListItem 5</li>
</ul>
```